# Ionic reuse header in other pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to reuse my HTML header for other pages in an Ionic 4 app.

My code is as follows. I have:

header.html

```
<ion-view>
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-6 class="font">
                <ion-avatar item-start>
                <img src="../../assets/imgs/ppc_logo.svg">
                </ion-avatar>
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col col-6 class="header_font">
            <p>BUILDER'S APP</p>
            </ion-col>  
        </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-view>
```

Home.html

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-content>
  <header> </header>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want to use this again as possibly a directive in other pages instead of copying the entire code in every page.

Please assist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what **components** are used for. Use the snippet of HTML that you want to reuse as component's **template**, and give the component a descriptive **selector**. Then you're ready to re-use it!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-reusable-component',
  template: `<div>template goes here </div>`
})
export class ReusableComponent { }
```

You can read more about [Angular components in the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#components).

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing that I need to import the component to in the module.ts file?

Comment: Yes. You should go though the [Tour of Heroes official Angular starter guide](https://angular.io/tutorial). It explains basic concepts about Angular through a series of examples.

Comment: Thanks, for anyone else who may need this I imported the component in the module.ts under declarations and entry components